# How to publish multiple build variants of an Android application to Artifactory from a Jenkins Pipeline using Jenkins Artifactory Plugin?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I have an android application having four build variants (devDebug, devRelease, tstDebug, tstRelease). I build them by a Jenkins Pipeline and want to upload them to our company's Artifactory server.
All four apk files are created, but only one of them gets uploaded. The one gets uploaded is devDebug, but I guess the one chosen is just due to some coinciedence.
When I build a quite similar Android *library* all four aar files get uploaded and get their classifiers set as expected.
In order to upload all variants I set android.publishNonDefault = true

I noticed that in the case of my application project 'archives' configuration contains com.android.build.gradle.internal.publishing.ApkPublishArtifact instances, while in the case of my library there are org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.publish.ArchivePublishArtifact_Decorated instances. This might be the problem for the Artifactory plugin, but this is just weak guessing.

My questions are:
How to upload all four apks from a single build and have their classifiers properly set either by fixing build configuration or converting them to an appropriate collection?
I need a generic solution if possible, since we have several android applications deployed the same way.
I'm also interested in why apk artifacts get collected differently from aars?

Please note, I'm using [Jenkins Artifactory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+-+Working+With+the+Pipeline+Jenkins+Plugin) (not Gradle Artifactory Plugin), and I'm using [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) (not the old Freestyle job), and I need a solution using these components.
I'm very new to Gradle and Android (I'm not even an Android developer, rather a release manager), but I'm OK with Pipeline and Artifactory.

I'm quite stuck at this point, any help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Details.

Versions:

```
Artifactory Professional 4.8.2 rev 40222
Jenkins ver. 2.40
Artifactory Plugin 2.9.1

com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

$ ./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-12-21 21:15:04 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     276bdcded730f53aa8c11b479986aafa58e124a6

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_31 (Oracle Corporation 25.31-b07)
OS:           Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}


// Plugins
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


allprojects {
    group = "eu.dorsum.cm.dummy.android.single"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId project.group
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName project.version
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            // configuration to access DEV backend comes here
        }
        tst {
            // configuration to access TST backend comes here
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
}

build.doLast {
  println "----------------------------------------------------------------"
  configurations.each { configuration ->
    println configuration
    configuration.allArtifacts.each { arti ->
      println "  a=$arti (${arti.class})"
    }
  }
}
```

init.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "${System.properties['artifactory.url']}/mvn-libs-all"
                credentials {
                    username = "${System.properties['artifactory.user']}"
                    password = "${System.properties['artifactory.password']}"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    rootProject.buildscript.repositories.each {
        repositories.add(it)
    }
}
```

pipeline script:

```
node {
    stage("Checkout") {
        echo "GRADLE_USER_HOME: ${env.GRADLE_USER_HOME}"
        checkout poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'WipeWorkspace']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'file:///c:/workspace/stash-dev/cmdum/dummy-android-single-apk']]]
    }

    stage("Build") {
        def server = Artifactory.server 'artifactory-loc'
        def rtGradle = Artifactory.newGradleBuild()
        rtGradle.resolver server: server, repo: 'mvn-libs-all'
        rtGradle.deployer server: server, repo: 'mvn-local'
        rtGradle.useWrapper = true
        rtGradle.usesPlugin = false

        withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool 'JDK 1.8'}", "GRADLE_USER_HOME=C:/Users/lkp/.gradle"]) {
            def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
            buildInfo.env.capture = true
            buildInfo = rtGradle.run buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: 'clean build artifactoryPublish -x lint', buildInfo: buildInfo, switches: "--debug -Dgradle.user.home=${env.GRADLE_USER_HOME}".toString()
            server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
        }
    }
}
```

---

Results:

In the case of Application project

Artifacts deployed to Artifactory server

[image]

Dependeny info of deployed apk generated by Artifactory

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.dorsum.cm.dummy.android.single</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy-android-single-apk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-20170208.200909-1</version>
    <type>apk</type>
</dependency>
```

built binaries

```
$ ls -1 build/outputs/apk/
dummy-android-single-apk-dev-debug.apk
dummy-android-single-apk-dev-debug-unaligned.apk
dummy-android-single-apk-dev-release-unsigned.apk
dummy-android-single-apk-tst-debug.apk
dummy-android-single-apk-tst-debug-unaligned.apk
dummy-android-single-apk-tst-release-unsigned.apk
```

While in the case of my library project

Artifactory repo (all 4 variants uploaded):

[image]

Generated dependency configs (classifiers set)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.dorsum.cm.dummy.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-android-aar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-20170208.200531-1</version>
    <classifier>devDebug</classifier>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.dorsum.cm.dummy.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-android-aar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-20170208.200531-1</version>
    <classifier>devRelease</classifier>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.dorsum.cm.dummy.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-android-aar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-20170208.200531-1</version>
    <classifier>tstDebug</classifier>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.dorsum.cm.dummy.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-android-aar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-20170208.200531-1</version>
    <classifier>tstRelease</classifier>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

Built binaries

```
$ ls -1 build/outputs/aar/
gradle-android-aar-dev-debug.aar
gradle-android-aar-dev-release.aar
gradle-android-aar-tst-debug.aar
gradle-android-aar-tst-release.aar
```